# WooCommerce add to cart with Api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

im trying to add a product to cart with Woocommerce API with this url `/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item`.

i use postman to send request but it returs `403 Forbidden` error:

```json
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_invalid_nonce",
  "message": "کلید سرّی نامعتبر است.",
  "data": {
    "status": 403
  }
}
```

Also i use swagger plugin in wordpress for API.

how can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need the nonce key.

you can GET site.com/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart

which will have the nonce in a header, and pass it back for your future requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a nonce. You can achieve that by making some changes in your `function.php` file which you can find in themes folder.
In wp you can achieve like this

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce('wc_store_api');
```

and if you are working with CMS or Rest APIs of Woocommerce then you will need an api to create a nonce every time you make a call to add product in the cart which you can do like this

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce('wc_store_api');

function expose_nonce() {
$nonce = wp_create_nonce('wc_store_api');
return $nonce;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
 register_rest_route('my-nonce/v1', '/get-nonce', array(
  'methods' => 'GET',
  'callback' => 'expose_nonce',
  ));
});
```

Now, your api will be something like this `wp-json/my-nonce/v1/get-nonce` to use response nonce in frontend for passing in `/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item`